# how to pass a variable from an HTML form to a perl cgi script?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I would like to use an HTML form to pass a variable to Perl CGI script so that I can process that variable, and then print it out on another HTML page.

Here is my HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/wTVQ5/.

Here is my Perl CGI script to links the HTML. Here is the way I would like to do it (since it uses less lines and probably more efficient).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
use CGI qw( :standard);
my $query = CGI->new;

# Process an HTTP request
my $user = $query->param('first_name');

# process $user... for example:
my $foo = "Foo";
my $str = $user . $foo;

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2>Hello $str - Second CGI Program</h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";

1;
```

Here's a way I read from a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm) and makes more sense to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

my ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST") {
   read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}else {
   $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}
# Split information into name/value pairs
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}
my $user = $FORM{first_name};

# process $user... for example:
my $foo = "Foo";
my $str = $user . $foo;

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2>Hello $str - Second CGI Program</h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";

1;
```

Both of these don't work properly BTW. When I click on the submit button on the HTML page, it just links me to the script instead of passing the variable, processing it, and printing out the HTML page.

Comment: on which server? apache?

Comment: I'm using Komodo Edit to write and view the HTML and an SSH server to test the final results. I've never used apache before and I don't have it installed, unfortunately.

Comment: You absolutely should *not* use the buggy parameter-processing code in your second example. The CGI module does this correctly. What is actually getting sent to your script? What happens if you dump all the params to the error log, for example?

Comment: but you need some kind of web server where you test that cgi script ... what are you using?

Comment: @cooldood3490, if you're not using a web server, how are you running this?

Comment: okay I just installed apache. `apt-get install apache2`

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
```

should be:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

or better:

```
print $query->header;
```

Also, ensure your web server was well configurated for CGI. And, if you have enough time, use a modern web application approach, there are many frameworks that may be better than CGI (Dancer, Mojolicious, OX, ...)

Comment: thanks Miguel. I made the changed as you said. I just installed apache. Now I'm gonna try to figure out how to run and test the cgi script using the apache server. I'll accept a best answer when I confirm that it works.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. When I click submit on the HTML page. It linked me to the perl cgi script instead of processing the input and displaying an HTML page. http://i.imgur.com/9WEm4uP.png

Answer (score 1):

I see your using CGI 'standard', no need really to initiate a CGI->new unless you just wanted to, also you said less lines, you could just do something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw( :standard );

my $user = param('first_name') || q/foo/;

print header, 
      start_html(-title => 'Hello'), h1('Hello ' . $user), end_html;
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. When I click submit on the HTML page. It linked me to the perl cgi script instead of processing the input and displaying an HTML page. http://i.imgur.com/9WEm4uP.png

Comment: What does your html for your <form> data and submit look like?

Comment: `<FORM action="name.cgi" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: First try using the full url to the script file, <form action="full/path/to/name.cgi", also do you have the write permissions set? chmod 0755?

Comment: Although sounds like apache is not configured to run .cgi files. Have you configured your web server yet?

Comment: I changed permissions on the name.html and name.cgi to chmod 0755 and using the full url to the script file but that didn't work. How do I configure my web server to run .cgi files? I'm reading through a tutorial on how to do it ATM. I will get back to you in a bit unless you know how to do it offhand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your httpd.conf with something like this.

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
<Directory /path/to/cgi/files>
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

If you are running this locally you could create a folder named **public_html** in your home directory structure and set this to run your scripts, you would just have to configure that also mapping it to that location.

Comment: thanks, I made the changes to the httpd.conf file. I'm getting this now: http://i.imgur.com/UDGGQHW.png even after changing permissions to chmod 0755. It wouldn't work before when I changed the html to the full path; I just have name.cgi in the same directory as the name.html. In any case, I'm getting closer.

Comment: The rule here is that Apache requires execute access to all folders in the path in order to serve files. Without this, you'll get a HTTP 403 (forbidden). It looks like you have your script in the main folder, you want to put it in your publc_html/cgi-bin or wherever your public directory is.